# How to display default menu in zen's sub theme

Tags: menu, drupal-7, themes, drupal-templates

This is my second question about drupal. I can not add blocks to my page because i'm working with a custom page. So I would like to display a custom menu in `page.tpl.php` file. Is this possible? If so the let me how to do it in my sub theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocks are inserted into regions, then regions are printed in the page.tpl.php.
Here you may find useful info: [Theming Guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/171194)